# trying to create a simple Accessors program

Tags: c#

I have 3 classes and one struct and I am trying to print out the total using accessors. The program prints the message the total is . No result is printed. 
trying to figure this out?

Main:

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        list.Add("1. option one");
        list.Add("2. option two");
        list.Add("3. option three");
        list.Add("4. option four");
        list.Add("5. option five");

        Console.WriteLine("1. option one");
        Console.WriteLine("2. option two");
        Console.WriteLine("3. option three");
        Console.WriteLine("4. option four");
        Console.WriteLine("5. option five");
        Console.WriteLine(" Pick  3 options ");

        UserInput usi = new UserInput();
        usi.Get();

        Console.WriteLine(" You Picked ");
        usi.print();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Program class:

```
class Program 
{
    private int A, B;
    public void GetAB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter A: ");
        A = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if ((A <= 0) || (A >= 6))
          //  Console.WriteLine("good");
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Number must be between 1-5");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter B: ");
        B = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if ((B <= 0) ||(B >=6))
             throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Number must be between 1-5");
    }
    public void PrintAB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A = {0}\tb = {1}\t", A, B);
    }
}
```

user input:

```
class UserInput : Program
{
    int C;

    public void Get()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Valid entries are 1-5");
            GetAB();
            Console.Write("Enter C: ");
            C = int.Parse((Console.ReadLine()));
            if ((C <= 0) || (C >= 6))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Number must be between 1-5");
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            // Show the user that 7 cannot be divided by 2.
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again ");

            System.Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }

    public int A
    { get; set; }
    public int B
    { get; set; }

    public void total()
    {
        int total = (A + B + C);
        Console.WriteLine(" Total is ", total);
    }

    public void print()
    {
        PrintAB();
        Console.WriteLine("C = {0}", C);
        total();
    }
}
```

total:

```
struct Total
{
    public int total { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please keep extra blank lines to a minimum. It makes the code more readable.

Comment: ok i thought it would help

Comment: Also, don't use `ArrayList` (plus you don't even use `list` anywhere).

Comment: Try this: `Console.WriteLine(" Total is {0}", total);` - see the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx)

Comment: Don’t make the name of private fields start with upper case characters. Only properties (and methods) should start with upper case characters. That way, you would have noticed what’s the problem here (the public properties `A` and `B` are different to the private fields `A` and `B` which are not accessible in your subtype).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Total is : ", total);
// In userInput.total()
```

It should be changed with:

```
Console.WriteLine("Total is : " + total);

OR

Console.WriteLine("Total is : {0}", total);
```

Comment: This helped with printing but when it prints it only prints the value of C. It doesnt print the total

Comment: Because in userInput class you have propeties 'A' and 'B'. So the compiler takes these properties as for A and B in the line (int total = (A + B + C);) and as you have these properties for nothing and there values were set to zero by the compiler, so the compiler take there values to zero. and A+B+C -> 0+0+C -> C. Thta is why you are getting value of only C.

Comment: @asdhjadgs Please see my comment to your question.